# Changing List item focus color onClick in functional components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

```
<li key={i} onClick={() => setBlogName(category.label) & handleListColor}>
  {category.name}
 <span style={{ float: 'right' }}>{category.total}</span>
</li>
```

I have this CSS style ready for it, but I want to change set the focus color when clicked.

```
.categories_Div li:first-child {
    line-height: 2.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #F38022;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.categories_Div li {
    line-height: 2.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

But I want to add focus to each lists when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it below.

```
focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Take a look https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_focus

working code http://jsfiddle.net/YFF6P/4/

Comment: Can you please post your updated code?. I Updated the working demo URL to my ans.